# cap production deploy | ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage Caused by: OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, puma, rbenv

I'm trying to deploy a Ruby-on-Rails project to my own dedicated server (ubuntu 2004.2022.1.0).

I'm using Ruby 3.0.2, Rbenv, Capistrano 3.17.1, Puma, Nginx.

But I'm failing on the deploy step.

If anyone can help me solve this issue, I'ld be very glad.

Here is the error message when using command :

> cap production deploy --trace

```
00:20 bundler:install
      The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied, skipping installation
** Execute deploy:updated
** Invoke deploy:compile_assets (first_time)
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env
** Execute deploy:compile_assets
** Invoke deploy:assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute deploy:assets:precompile
00:20 deploy:assets:precompile
      01 bundle exec rake assets:precompile
      01 rake aborted!
      01 ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage
/home/deploy/deploy.fr/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:209:in `rescue in _decrypt'/home/deploy/deploy.fr/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:186:in `_decrypt'
/home/deploy/deploy.fr/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:160:in `decrypt_and_verify'

Caused by:
OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError:
/home/deploy/deploy.fr/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:204:in `final'
/home/deploy/deploy.fr/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:204:in `_decrypt'
/home/deploy/deploy.fr/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:160:in `decrypt_and_verify'(See full trace by running task with --trace)
#<Thread:0x00005638e7884638 /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.3/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.3/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing as deploy@deploy.fr: rake exit status: 1 (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: rake aborted!
ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage
/home/deploy/deploy.fr/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:209:in `rescue in 
...
```

capistrano.log (only the failed lines)

```
 DEBUG [c2a2b569] Command: [ -f /home/deploy/deploy.fr/current/REVISION ]
 DEBUG [c2a2b569] Finished in 0.105 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [0c97213c] Running [ -L /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/config/database.yml ] as deploy@deploy.fr
 DEBUG [0c97213c] Command: [ -L /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/config/database.yml ]
 DEBUG [0c97213c] Finished in 0.111 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [9a1b2e0b] Running [ -f /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/config/database.yml ] as deploy@deploy.fr
 DEBUG [9a1b2e0b] Command: [ -f /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/config/database.yml ]
 DEBUG [9a1b2e0b] Finished in 0.079 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [2c6d0708] Running [ -L /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/config/secrets.yml ] as deploy@deploy.fr
 DEBUG [2c6d0708] Command: [ -L /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/config/secrets.yml ]
 DEBUG [2c6d0708] Finished in 0.068 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [d332b2bb] Running [ -f /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/config/secrets.yml ] as deploy@deploy.fr
 DEBUG [d332b2bb] Command: [ -f /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/config/secrets.yml ]
 DEBUG [d332b2bb] Finished in 0.115 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [c1307965] Running [ -L /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/config/master.key ] as deploy@deploy.fr
 DEBUG [c1307965] Command: [ -L /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/config/master.key ]
 DEBUG [c1307965] Finished in 0.114 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [3098a995] Running [ -f /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/config/master.key ] as deploy@deploy.fr
 DEBUG [3098a995] Command: [ -f /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/config/master.key ]
 DEBUG [3098a995] Finished in 0.074 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [ca0c9dee] Running [ -L /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/log ] as deploy@deploy.fr
 DEBUG [ca0c9dee] Command: [ -L /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/log ]
 DEBUG [ca0c9dee] Finished in 0.118 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [8bba8809] Running [ -L /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/tmp/pids ] as deploy@deploy.fr
 DEBUG [8bba8809] Command: [ -L /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/tmp/pids ]
 DEBUG [8bba8809] Finished in 0.114 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [2a5f23c1] Finished in 0.114 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [a2b2d01b] Running [ -d /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/tmp/cache ] as deploy@deploy.fr
 DEBUG [a2b2d01b] Command: [ -d /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/tmp/cache ]
 DEBUG [a2b2d01b] Finished in 0.072 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [b2059567] Running [ -L /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/tmp/sockets ] as deploy@deploy.fr
 DEBUG [b2059567] Command: [ -L /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/tmp/sockets ]
 DEBUG [b2059567] Finished in 0.073 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [eef74f83] Running [ -d /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/tmp/sockets ] as deploy@deploy.fr
 DEBUG [eef74f83] Command: [ -d /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/tmp/sockets ]
 DEBUG [eef74f83] Finished in 0.115 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [e4ed291f] Running [ -L /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/tmp/webpacker ] as deploy@deploy.fr
 DEBUG [e4ed291f] Command: [ -L /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/tmp/webpacker ]
 DEBUG [e4ed291f] Finished in 0.118 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [9a3182f0] Running [ -d /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/tmp/webpacker ] as deploy@deploy.fr
 DEBUG [9a3182f0] Command: [ -d /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/tmp/webpacker ]
 DEBUG [9a3182f0] Finished in 0.074 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [50e4ca0b] Running [ -L /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/vendor ] as deploy@deploy.fr
 DEBUG [50e4ca0b] Command: [ -L /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/vendor ]
 DEBUG [50e4ca0b] Finished in 0.073 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [2224ab16] Running [ -L /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/storage ] as deploy@deploy.fr
 DEBUG [2224ab16] Command: [ -L /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/storage ]
 DEBUG [2224ab16] Finished in 0.073 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [9dbdf796] Running [ -L /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/public/assets ] as deploy@deploy.fr
 DEBUG [9dbdf796] Command: [ -L /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/public/assets ]
 DEBUG [9dbdf796] Finished in 0.074 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [f5079584] Running [ -d /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/public/assets ] as deploy@deploy.fr
 DEBUG [f5079584] Command: [ -d /home/deploy/deploy.fr/releases/20220908112310/public/assets ]
 DEBUG [f5079584] Finished in 0.118 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
```

deploy.rb :

```
# deploy.rb

# config valid for current version and patch releases of Capistrano
lock "~> 3.17.1"

set :application, "deploy.fr"
# set :repo_url, "git@example.com:me/my_repo.git"
set :repo_url, "/home/deploy/git_deploy_fr_nf"

# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
set :deploy_to, "/home/deploy/deploy.fr"

# Default value for :format is :airbrussh.
# set :format, :airbrussh

# You can configure the Airbrussh format using :format_options.
# These are the defaults.
# set :format_options, command_output: true, log_file: "log/capistrano.log", color: :auto, truncate: :auto

# Default value for :pty is false
# set :pty, true

# Default value for :linked_files is []
append :linked_files, "config/database.yml", "config/secrets.yml", "config/master.key"

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
append :linked_dirs, "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "tmp/sockets", "tmp/webpacker", "vendor", "storage"

set :nginx_config_name, 'deploy_fr_nf'
set :nginx_server_name, 'deploy.fr'
set :puma_workers, 2 # nombre de coeurs du serveur dédié

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }

# Default value for local_user is ENV['USER']
# set :local_user, -> { `git config user.name`.chomp }

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
# set :keep_releases, 5

# Uncomment the following to require manually verifying the host key before first deploy.
# set :ssh_options, verify_host_key: :secure
```

Gemfile :

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "3.0.2"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "main"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.3", ">= 7.0.3.1"

# The original asset pipeline for Rails [https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails]
gem "sprockets-rails"

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem "pg", "~> 1.4.3"

# Use the Puma web server [https://github.com/puma/puma]
gem "puma", "~> 5.0"

# Use JavaScript with ESM import maps [https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails]
gem "importmap-rails"

# Hotwire's SPA-like page accelerator [https://turbo.hotwired.dev]
gem "turbo-rails"

# Hotwire's modest JavaScript framework [https://stimulus.hotwired.dev]
gem "stimulus-rails"

# Build JSON APIs with ease [https://github.com/rails/jbuilder]
gem "jbuilder"



# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem "redis", "~> 4.0"

# Use Kredis to get higher-level data types in Redis [https://github.com/rails/kredis]
# gem "kredis"

# Use Active Model has_secure_password [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html#securepassword]
# gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.7"

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem "bootsnap", require: false

# Use Sass to process CSS
# gem "sassc-rails"

# Use Active Storage variants [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images]
# gem "image_processing", "~> 1.2"

group :development, :test do
  # See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debug-gem
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
end

group :development do
  # Use console on exceptions pages [https://github.com/rails/web-console]
  gem "web-console"

  # Add speed badges [https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler]
  # gem "rack-mini-profiler"

  # Speed up commands on slow machines / big apps [https://github.com/rails/spring]
  # gem "spring"

  # déploiement
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.17', '>= 3.17'
  gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.6'
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '~> 2.2'
  gem 'capistrano3-puma' , group: :development
  gem 'ed25519', '>= 1.2', '< 2.0'
  gem 'bcrypt_pbkdf', '>= 1.0', '< 2.0'
end

group :test do
  # Use system testing [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing]
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "webdrivers"
end
```

Capfile

```
# Capfile

# Load DSL and set up stages
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Include default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'

# Load the SCM plugin appropriate to your project:
#
# require 'capistrano/scm/hg'
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Hg
# or
# require 'capistrano/scm/svn'
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Svn
# or
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git
# install_plugin Capistrano::Puma
require 'capistrano/scm/git'
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

# Include tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails
#   https://github.com/capistrano/passenger

# require 'capistrano/rbenv'
# require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/bundler'

# Important: Puma configuration should come after rvm or rbenv
require 'capistrano/puma'
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma  # Default puma tasks
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma::Workers  # if you want to control the workers (in cluster mode)
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma::Jungle # if you need the jungle tasks
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma::Monit  # if you need the monit tasks
require 'capistrano/puma/nginx'
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma::Nginx  # if you want to upload a nginx site template

# require 'capistrano/chruby'
# require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
# require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
# require 'capistrano/passenger'

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (7.0.3.1)
      actionpack (= 7.0.3.1)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3.1)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (7.0.3.1)
      actionpack (= 7.0.3.1)
      activejob (= 7.0.3.1)
      activerecord (= 7.0.3.1)
      activestorage (= 7.0.3.1)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3.1)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
      net-imap
      net-pop
      net-smtp
    actionmailer (7.0.3.1)
      actionpack (= 7.0.3.1)
      actionview (= 7.0.3.1)
      activejob (= 7.0.3.1)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      net-imap
      net-pop
      net-smtp
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (7.0.3.1)
      actionview (= 7.0.3.1)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3.1)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actiontext (7.0.3.1)
      actionpack (= 7.0.3.1)
      activerecord (= 7.0.3.1)
      activestorage (= 7.0.3.1)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3.1)
      globalid (>= 0.6.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (7.0.3.1)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    activejob (7.0.3.1)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3.1)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (7.0.3.1)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3.1)
    activerecord (7.0.3.1)
      activemodel (= 7.0.3.1)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3.1)
    activestorage (7.0.3.1)
      actionpack (= 7.0.3.1)
      activejob (= 7.0.3.1)
      activerecord (= 7.0.3.1)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3.1)
      marcel (~> 1.0)
      mini_mime (>= 1.1.0)
    activesupport (7.0.3.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
      minitest (>= 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 2.0)
    addressable (2.8.1)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 6.0)
    airbrussh (1.4.1)
      sshkit (>= 1.6.1, != 1.7.0)
    bcrypt_pbkdf (1.1.0)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.13.0)
      msgpack (~> 1.2)
    builder (3.2.4)
    capistrano (3.17.1)
      airbrussh (>= 1.0.0)
      i18n
      rake (>= 10.0.0)
      sshkit (>= 1.9.0)
    capistrano-bundler (2.1.0)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
    capistrano-rails (1.6.2)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      capistrano-bundler (>= 1.1, < 3)
    capistrano-rbenv (2.2.0)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      sshkit (~> 1.3)
    capistrano3-puma (5.2.0)
      capistrano (~> 3.7)
      capistrano-bundler
      puma (>= 4.0, < 6.0)
    capybara (3.37.1)
      addressable
      matrix
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (>= 1.5, < 3.0)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    childprocess (4.1.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.10)
    crass (1.0.6)
    debug (1.6.2)
      irb (>= 1.3.6)
      reline (>= 0.3.1)
    digest (3.1.0)
    ed25519 (1.3.0)
    erubi (1.11.0)
    globalid (1.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0)
    i18n (1.12.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    importmap-rails (1.1.5)
      actionpack (>= 6.0.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    io-console (0.5.11)
    irb (1.4.1)
      reline (>= 0.3.0)
    jbuilder (2.11.5)
      actionview (>= 5.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    loofah (2.18.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (1.0.2)
    matrix (0.4.2)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mini_mime (1.1.2)
    minitest (5.16.3)
    msgpack (1.5.6)
    net-imap (0.2.3)
      digest
      net-protocol
      strscan
    net-pop (0.1.1)
      digest
      net-protocol
      timeout
    net-protocol (0.1.3)
      timeout
    net-scp (1.2.1)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-smtp (0.3.1)
      digest
      net-protocol
      timeout
    net-ssh (7.0.1)
    nio4r (2.5.8)
    nokogiri (1.13.8-x86_64-linux)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    pg (1.4.3)
    public_suffix (5.0.0)
    puma (5.6.5)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    racc (1.6.0)
    rack (2.2.4)
    rack-test (2.0.2)
      rack (>= 1.3)
    rails (7.0.3.1)
      actioncable (= 7.0.3.1)
      actionmailbox (= 7.0.3.1)
      actionmailer (= 7.0.3.1)
      actionpack (= 7.0.3.1)
      actiontext (= 7.0.3.1)
      actionview (= 7.0.3.1)
      activejob (= 7.0.3.1)
      activemodel (= 7.0.3.1)
      activerecord (= 7.0.3.1)
      activestorage (= 7.0.3.1)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3.1)
      bundler (>= 1.15.0)
      railties (= 7.0.3.1)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.4.3)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    railties (7.0.3.1)
      actionpack (= 7.0.3.1)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3.1)
      method_source
      rake (>= 12.2)
      thor (~> 1.0)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.5)
    rake (13.0.6)
    regexp_parser (2.5.0)
    reline (0.3.1)
      io-console (~> 0.5)
    rexml (3.2.5)
    rubyzip (2.3.2)
    selenium-webdriver (4.4.0)
      childprocess (>= 0.5, < 5.0)
      rexml (~> 3.2, >= 3.2.5)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2, < 3.0)
      websocket (~> 1.0)
    sprockets (4.1.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.4.2)
      actionpack (>= 5.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sshkit (1.21.3)
      net-scp (>= 1.1.2)
      net-ssh (>= 2.8.0)
    stimulus-rails (1.1.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    strscan (3.0.4)
    thor (1.2.1)
    timeout (0.3.0)
    turbo-rails (1.1.1)
      actionpack (>= 6.0.0)
      activejob (>= 6.0.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    tzinfo (2.0.5)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    web-console (4.2.0)
      actionview (>= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    webdrivers (5.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rubyzip (>= 1.3.0)
      selenium-webdriver (~> 4.0)
    websocket (1.2.9)
    websocket-driver (0.7.5)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    zeitwerk (2.6.0)

PLATFORMS
  x86_64-linux

DEPENDENCIES
  bcrypt_pbkdf (>= 1.0, < 2.0)
  bootsnap
  capistrano (~> 3.17, >= 3.17)
  capistrano-rails (~> 1.6)
  capistrano-rbenv (~> 2.2)
  capistrano3-puma
  capybara
  debug
  ed25519 (>= 1.2, < 2.0)
  importmap-rails
  jbuilder
  pg (~> 1.4.3)
  puma (~> 5.0)
  rails (~> 7.0.3, >= 7.0.3.1)
  selenium-webdriver
  sprockets-rails
  stimulus-rails
  turbo-rails
  tzinfo-data
  web-console
  webdrivers

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 3.0.2p107

BUNDLED WITH
   2.2.22
```

Comment: it failed to install strscan. It says results logged to ... so you need to look in the file where the failure was logged and see the cause of the failure to install strscan

Answer (score 1):

I solved the error by removing links (this 2 lines) from deploy.rb :

```
append :linked_files, "config/database.yml", "config/secrets.yml", "config/master.key"

append :linked_dirs, "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "tmp/sockets", "tmp/webpacker", "vendor", "storage"
```

Comment: That does not look good. It looks like you manage your key via your repository which is a security hole.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at  https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#environmental-security

You have to copy config/master.key to deployed folder.

If you want regenerate the security files, you can delete this files:

```
config/master.key
config/credentials.yml.enc
```

And run this command to regenerate then

```
rails credentials:edit
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy your `credentials.yml.enc` to your `shared/config/` folder.
Then add `config/credentials.hml.enc` to the `:linked_files` line in your `deploy.rb` file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).